# JTable getColumnClass warning

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have tried searching, but no one seems to have the answer.

I use a JTable in order to have a table with people listed and I wanted to put an ImageIcon so  from what I have read I have to override the default method in order to return an icon and not String.

This is what I use:

```
public Class getColumnClass(int column)   
{   
    return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();   
}
```

But eclipse underlines the return type "Class" in yellow and gives me this warning:

> Type safety: The return type Class for getColumnClass(int) from the
>   type new JTable(){} needs unchecked conversion to conform to Class
>   from the type JTable

And its only suggestion is to suppress it. I am not sure if I even get the warning properly, can someone try to explain me what exactly does it mean and help me find a good solution which won't be to suppress it?

Comment: What if you change the return type to `Class<?>`?

Comment: You should never rely on the column value to determine the class type. What happens if the value is `null` or you have no rows? Instead, you should returning a concrete class type (ie `String.class`, `Date.class`, etc). Each column should only represent a single class type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return type of `Class` is a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) which produces a compiler warning. You need to add a generic wildcard to the return type to eliminate this warning:

```
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column)
```

See: [Generic Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: So basically ? is a wildcard? Can you tell me what should I search to read about this one as I was totaly unaware of it?

Also thank you for the solution.

Comment: It's NOT equivalent to Class<Object>. Class<Object> is Object.class. Class<?> is SomeUnknownClass.class.